# Sums of injective modules, products of projective modules?

Tags: homological-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

1. Under what assumptions on a noncommutative ring R does a countable direct sum of injective left R-modules necessarily have a finite injective dimension?
2. Analogously, under what assumptions on R does a countable product of projective left R-modules necessarily have a finite projective dimension?

These questions arise in the study of the coderived and contraderived categories of (CDG-)modules, or, if one wishes, the homotopy categories of unbounded complexes of injective or projective modules.

There are some obvious sufficient conditions and some less-so-obvious ones.  For both #1 and #2, it clearly suffices that R have a finite left homological dimension.

More interestingly, in both cases it suffices that R be left Gorenstein, i.e., such that the classes of left R-modules of finite projective dimension and left R-modules of finite injective dimension coincide.

For #1, it also suffices that R be left Noetherian.  For #2, it suffices that R be right coherent and such that any flat left module has a finite projective dimension.

Any other sufficient conditions?

Comment: Just wanted to say that this question is interesting to me, but you have covered all the cases that occur to me.  One comment: I think your question is equivalent to asking when finite injective dimension modules are closed under (countable) direct sums, and the obvious dual thing for finite projective dimension.  

Comment: I think the following assertions (and their obvious duals) are true: if a countable sum of injective R-modules always has a finite injective dimension, then this dimension is bounded by a constant d depending on R only.  Moreover, a countable sum of R-modules of injective dimensions not exceeding n then never exceeds n+d.

However, I do not see why what you are saying is true.  E.g., if R is a Noetherian ring for which there are modules of arbitrarily high finite injective dimension, then a countable sum of such modules would have an infinite injective dimension, providing a counterexample.

Comment: How about a much easier question: when are sums of injective themselves injective; similarly for projectives? Over a field or the ring of dual numbers $k[a]/(a^2)$, injectives=projectives, so the answer is yes. Over a PID, sums of divisible modules are divisible, so yes for injectives (and no for projectives e.g. over $R=\mathbb Z$). Are there any other interesting cases?

Comment: The answer to this easier question is well-known.  Sums of injective left R-modules are injective if and only if R is left Noetherian.  Products of projective left R-modules are projective if and only if two conditions hold: 1. products of flat left R-modules are flat (which is equivalent to R being right coherent) and 2. all flat left R-modules are projective (in which case R is called left perfect).  Concerning the latter assertion, see Chase, "Direct products of modules", and Bass, "Finitistic dimension and a homological generalization of semi-primary rings".

Comment: Good to know! Is there a typo in 1 (left coherent instead of right) or a typo in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_ring ?

Comment: The typo is in Wikipedia.  The argument is very simple: over a right coherent ring, any short exact sequence of right modules is a direct limit of short exact sequences of finitely presented right modules; while the tensor product with a finitely presented right module commutes with any direct products of left modules.

Comment: More general statement for VA's question. If C is a locally noetherian category, then any injective in C is direct sum of indecomposable injectives in C. This can be used to prove that inverse image functor of open immersion preserves injectives

Comment: @Shizhuo: you mean, the inverse image for quasi-coherent sheaves on a Noetherian scheme, I guess.  And it is also true that the class of injectives in a locally Noetherian Grothendieck category (e.g., the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on a Noetherian scheme) is closed under infinite direct sums.

Comment: Yes, it is true. 

Answer (score 2):

For #1, it suffices that $R$ be left coherent and such that any fp-injective left $R$-module has finite injective dimension.  In particular, these conditions hold when $R$ is left coherent and every left ideal in $R$ has a set of generators of the cardinality not exceeding $\aleph_n$ for some nonnegative integer $n$ (e.g., a countable set of generators).  See Section 2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00700 .